# Why is this question highlighted in results?

Tags: discussion

http://abevoelker.com/tmp/highlighted.png

Sorry if I am missing something obvious - I searched but didn't find anything relevant.

The only interesting thing that I see is that the apparent author on the [result list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=newest&pagesize=15) ([Clueless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165876/clueless)) is not the same as on the [actual question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755566/python-im-getting-an-indented-block-error-on-the-last-3-quotes-of-my-co) ([WaxProlix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583979/waxprolix)).

And looking back at the result list just now before submitting, the correct author is now listed ([WaxProlix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583979/waxprolix))... ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about the highlighted question, that would be either because you put one of the tags that the question has (probably [python](/questions/tagged/python) in this case) into your list of favourite tags, or that you've used the site for long enough such that the system recognises that tag as one of your field of interest. Either way, the highlighting is for filtering purposes - to highlight to you posts which you want to see.

To answer the second part of your question, the homepage question list (in your picture) lists the last user which has performed an action (edited, answered) on that question, while the list you linked to (`/questions?sort=newest`) lists the user which asked the question.

The two lists serve different purposes, and therefore the user and timestamp listed is also different.

Comment: Python isn't in my favorite tags... but expect is!  I did check the answers, comments and question revisions but that user didn't show up.  I guess they performed one of those actions and then deleted it.  Thanks for answering my questions!